# Highcharts Navigator labels are not precise

Tags: highcharts

When using Highcharts [Navigator](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator) the docs mention:

> Unless data is explicitly defined on navigator.series, the data is borrowed from the first series in the chart.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        navigator: {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: usdeur
        }]
    });
});
```

But as in the example of Highcharts Navigator itself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/navigator/series/) the data is not exactly the data from the first series in the chart. In this example the date is between 2007-2015 but navigator only shows 2008-2014. Is there a way to override this option? How can I change this?

Comment: The data only starts in mid 2007, so the first year boundary is 2008. What would you like the navigator to show ?

Comment: I'd prefer the navigator to show 2007-2015. Is that possible?

Comment: Data in the navigator is printed according to main series. So when series begins in mid 2007, navigator also prints half of 2007 and then equal years. In case when you print whole year in navigator, then empty points will exist.

Comment: From what I can see, the navigator data is complete - as in, it is all of the data that is present in the chart. Your issue seems to be with the labels.  I would suggest updating the question and title to reflect that.